# javascript split and for functions

Tags: javascript, php

hi im trying to show multiple images with split ans for functios but im having problems:

the php returns a string with links separated by comas and i need to show as image each record this is the code:

```
var msg 'files/uploads/1688482n.jpg,files/uploads/10904912__n.jpg,files/uploads/10907098_0_o.jpg';
    var img = explode(msg)
        $('.mensage').html(img);//A el div con la clase msg, le insertamos el mensaje en formato  thml
        $('.mensage').show('slow');//Mostramos el div.
        $("#im").val(""+msg+"");
    }
    function explode(t) {
        var txt = t,
            list = txt.split(","),
            tt = "";

        console.log(list);


        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            (tt += ("<img style='width:290px;height:190px;' class='img-tm2' src='"+i+"'><br>")); //This gets its place
        }
        return tt
    }
```

in return im having this in the console:
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:

so how i can display each image right?

the problem is showing like this:

```
<img style="width:290px;height:190px;" class="img-tm2" src="0">
<img style="width:290px;height:190px;" class="img-tm2" src="1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few bugs. Here is a corrected code:

```
var msg = 'n.jpg,o.jpg';
var img = explode(msg);
$('.mensage').val(img);//A el div con la clase msg, le insertamos el mensaje en formato  thml
$('.mensage').show('slow');//Mostramos el div.
$("#im").html(img);
function explode(txt) {
    var list = txt.split(",");
    tt = "";
    console.log(list);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        tt += "<img style='width:290px;height:190px;' class='img-tm2' src='"+list[i]+"'><br />"; //This gets its place
    }
    return tt;
}
```

Trying to enumerate them:

- missing semicolons at the end of statements;
- var msg = (missing "=");
- i instead of list[i];

Answer (score 0):

Why do you print i and not that ?

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    (tt += ("<img style='width:290px;height:190px;' class='img-tm2' src='"+list[i]+"'><br>")); //This gets its place
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use for each instead of for loop.

```
            for each(var url in list) {
                (tt += ("<img style='width:290px;height:190px;' class='img-tm2' src='"+url+"'><br>")); //This gets its place
            }
            return tt
        }
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  in   for each(url in list) {

Comment: Made the correction in code above. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in